# How do I get Rest Assured to return the text (non-encrypted or streamed) value in my REST response?

Tags: java, rest

I recently moved over to Java and am attempting to write some REST tests against the netflix REST service.

I'm having an issue in that my response using rest assured either wants to send a gzip encoded response or "InputStream", neither of which provide the actual XML text in the content of the response.  I discovered the "Accept-Encoding" header yet making that blank doesn't seem to be the solution.  With .Net I never had to mess with this and I can't seem to find the proper means of returning a human readable response.

My code:

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://api-public.netflix.com";
RestAssured.port = 80;

Response myResponse = given().header("Accept-Encoding", "").given().auth().oauth(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, secretToken).param("term", "star wars").get("/catalog/titles/autocomplete");
```

My response object has a "content" value with nothing but references to buffers, wrapped streams etc.  Trying to get a ToString() of the response doesn't work.  None of the examples I've seen seem to work in my case.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess in Java land everything is returned as an input stream.  Using a stream reader grabbed me the data I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me:

```
given().config(RestAssured.config().decoderConfig(DecoderConfig.decoderConfig().noContentDecoders())).get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
String responseJson = get("/languages/").asString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Until its version 1.9.0, Rest-assured has been providing by default in the requests the header "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate" with no way of changing it.

See
https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/issues/detail?id=154